# Vala: Free GChecksum after operation to get a correct MD5 hash

Tags: hash, gtk, vala, md5sum

I'm learing Vala and i'm trying to build a Gtk+ Gui wich output an MD5 hash of a file. 
Currently i'm using [valadoc.org](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Checksum) to code my application and i'm using  GLib.Checksum to calculate the checksum. GLib.Checksum handle MD5, SHA1, SHA256 and SHA512 (Found in the documentation).
So i used the code in the documentation in order to calculate the hash of an input file's path. I found that Vala didn't free the GChecksum automatically and i don't how to do it manually.

Thanks for the help.

This is my Vala code:

```
private string HashSum( string path, string hash){
    Checksum checksum = new Checksum(ChecksumType.MD5);
    FileStream stream = FileStream.open(path, "rb");
    //var stream = File.new_for_path(path).read();

   uint8 fbuf[100];
   size_t size;

   while ((size = stream.read(fbuf)) > 0){
      checksum.update(fbuf, size);
    }
   unowned string digest = checksum.get_string();
   stdout.printf("%s: %s\n", path, digest);

   return @"$hash hash: $digest";
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that it was not freed? In the generated code, I see a free call generated. What version of Vala are you using?

Comment: I'm using Vala 0.22.1.
And i figure it out when i compare the output MD5sum of my application and the md5sum in my Ubuntu PC. 
This is how i was wodring that the Checksum is not freed: When i try to make multiple sums, the output change. And today when i opened my PC the output was correct. And when i recompile my application using --pkg gtk+-3.0 the output changed ! 
i don't know why really ... i'm supposing that it's a freed problem.

Comment: @apmasell: Thanks for your answer! The problem was with my valac version. I upgraded it to Vala 0.30.0 and the output is correct now.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was with my Valac version. I upgraded it to the last one i found in my Ubuntu repositories which is: Vala 0.30.0 . And the output now is correct.